# Custom ColorFunction/ColorData in ArrayPlot (and similar functions)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is related to Simon's [question on changing default ColorData](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/121) in Mathematica. While  the solutions all addressed the issue of changing `ColorData` in line plots, I didn't quite find the discussion helpful in changing the `ColorFunction`/`ColorData` in `ContourPlot`/`ArrayPlot`/`Plot3D`, etc.

> **TLDR:** Is there a way to get mma to use custom colors in ArrayPlot/ContourPlot/etc.

---

Consider the following example plot of the function `sin(x^2+y^3)` that I created in MATLAB:

[image]

Now doing the same in mma as:

```
xMax = 3; yMax = 3;
img = Transpose@
   Table[Sin[y ^3 + x^2], {x, -xMax, xMax, 0.01}, {y, -yMax, yMax, 
     0.01}];
plot = ArrayPlot[img, ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameTicks -> {FindDivisions[{0, (img // Dimensions // First) - 1},
       4], FindDivisions[{0, (img // Dimensions // Last) - 1}, 4], 
     None, None}, 
   DataReversed -> 
    True] /. (FrameTicks -> {x_, 
      y_}) :> (FrameTicks -> {x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_Integer} :> {a, 
         2 xMax (b/((img // Dimensions // First) - 1) - 1/2)}, 
      y /. {a_?NumericQ, b_Integer} :> {a, 
         2 yMax (b/((img // Dimensions // Last) - 1) - 1/2)}})
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

I prefer the rich, bright colors in MATLAB to mma's pastel/dull colors. How do I get mma to use these colors, if I have the RGB values of the colormap from MATLAB?

You can download the RGB values of the default colormap in MATLAB, and import it into mma as

```
cMap = Transpose@Import["path-to-colorMapJet.mat", {"HDF5", 
      "Datasets", "cMap"}];
```

`cMap` is a `64x3` array of values between `0` and `1`.

Just to give you some background, here's some relevant text from the MathWorks [documentation on colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html)

> A colormap is an m-by-3 matrix of real
>   numbers between 0.0 and 1.0. Each row
>   is an RGB vector that defines one
>   color. The kth row of the colormap
>   defines the kth color, where map(k,:)
>   = [r(k) g(k) b(k)]) specifies the intensity of red, green, and blue.

Here `map=cMap`, and `m=64`.

I tried poking at `ColorDataFunction`, and I see that the `ColorData` format is similar to the `colormap`. However, I'm not sure how to get `ArrayPlot` to use it (and presumably it ought to be the same for other plot functions).

---

Also, since my exercise here is purely to reach a level of comfort in mma, similar to what I have in MATLAB, I'd appreciate comments and suggestions on improving my code. Specifically, I'm not too satisfied with my hack of a way to "fix" the `FrameTicks`... surely there must be a nicer/easier way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"] or ColorData["TemperatureMap"] instead of "Rainbow"? These produce a much brighter plot.

Comment: There are graduate advisors older than yoda?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace your `ColorData["Rainbow"]` with this one:

```
Function[Blend[RGBColor @@@ cMap, Slot[1]]]
```

and you get this:

[image]

---

As to your second question, you can do it this way:

```
xMax = 3; yMax = 3;
img = Transpose@
   Table[Sin[y^3 + x^2], {x, -xMax, xMax, 0.01}, {y, -yMax, yMax, 
     0.01}];
plot = ArrayPlot[img, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[Blend[RGBColor @@@ cMap, Slot[1]]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  DataRange -> {{-xMax, xMax}, {-yMax, yMax}}, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

but why don't you use DensityPlot?

```
DensityPlot[Sin[y^3 + x^2], {x, -xMax, xMax}, {y, -yMax, yMax}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[Blend[RGBColor @@@ cMap, Slot[1]]], 
 PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Note that in the second plot the y-range labeling is reversed. That's because it takes the DataReversed setting into account. ArrayPlot plots the rows of the arrays in the same order as they appear when the array's content is printed on screen. So the first row is plotted on top and the last row is plotted at the bottom. High row values correspond to low y-values and vice versa. DataReversed->True corrects for this phenomenon, but in this case it also 'corrects' the y values. A  workaround is to fill the array starting from high y-values going down to the lower ones. In that case you don't need DataReversed:

```
xMax = 3; yMax = 3;
img = Transpose@
   Table[Sin[y^3 + x^2], {x, -xMax, xMax, 0.01}, {y, 
     yMax, -yMax, -0.01}];
plot = ArrayPlot[img, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[Blend[RGBColor @@@ cMap, Slot[1]]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  DataRange -> {{-xMax, xMax}, {-yMax, yMax}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Sjoerd: That's neat! `DataRange` saves me a lot of unnecessary replacing. You're right, I could've done it using `DensityPlot` too. I just default to `ArrayPlot` because all my output from MATLAB (which I then import to mma) are arrays. This was just an example that had a neat functional form.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Why does `DataRange` flip the vertical axis? If you look at the last two plots in your answer, the yaxis tick marks are flipped in the `ArrayPlot` figure.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks. I can also use `Reverse@` for arrays where I don't control the fill-in order.

Comment: For `DensityPlot` it should be faster with `MaxRecursion -> 0` added.  Also, is there some reason for the long form rather than `ColorFunction -> (Blend[RGBColor @@@ cMap, #] &)` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, it's the same. A warning for everyone who's going to use that version: indeed, you have to take care the parentheses are there because of the -> having higher precedence than &

Comment: By the way, congratulations on your fourth Enlightened badge.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you track that one way or another? (SO API?)

Comment: No, I just realized you had the first reply, it was accepted, and (thanks to my vote ;-) has a score of 10, so that should give you a badge.  I checked your profile to see that it was your fourth!  (I only have one.)  By the way, I have started using my profile to post notes (view it to see what I mean).  You may wish to do the same.  It seems like a good way for us to draw attention to something without having to @name everybody.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard but does it indeed draw attention? This seems to be suited for some longer term goals, not quick response stuff. Doesn't scale either. Anyway, I already had a note there, but a quite different one...

Comment: I grant it only works if we look at each other's profiles from time to time.  I did mean it to be for long-term stuff.  For example, the bold part of the linked question in mine has gone unanswered for some while now.  If I don't get a response this way, I will have to post it as a separate question.  Is there nothing you would like some extra eyes on, without having to ask people though comments?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One of the shortcomings of SO is that there's no room to publish neat things without a corresponding question. The environment would be suited for it, but not the rules. The reverse is true for the mathgroup: no rules on content (except about using the 'other' M-word), but severe disadvantages (extreme delays, no graphics, no code, no editing, no voting, hyperlink unfriendly). G'night again. I'm off to my SO.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I'm curious... what's the other M-word? I'm guessing MATLAB or Maple, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @yoda You guessed it right. Try to ask a question like "I know how to do this in Matlab, but how do I do this in Mathematica?". The moderator will change this in "I know how to do this in another system, but how ...". I guess this is to prevent flame wars, but I feel comparing modus operandi in various CA systems shouldn't necessarily end in that.

Answer (score 19):

(I hope this isn't too late an addendum.)

As it turns out, one doesn't even need to keep the entire set of sixty-four `RGBColor[]` directives around for the purpose of using with `Blend[]` A clue that this is certainly the case is afforded by `ListPlot[]`s of the columns of `cMap`:

```
{rr, gg, bb} = Transpose[Rationalize[cMap]];
GraphicsGrid[{MapThread[
   ListPlot[#1, DataRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     GridLines -> {{1/9, 23/63, 13/21, 55/63}, None}, 
     PlotLabel -> #2] &, {{rr, gg, bb}, {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}}]}]
```

[image: LisPlot[]s of RGB components of MATLAB's jet colormap]

and we see that implicitly, the functions representing these components are *piecewise linear*. Since `Blend[]` necessarily does linear interpolation between colors, if we can find those colors that correspond to "corners" in the piecewise linear graphs, we can eliminate all the other colors in between those corners (since `Blend[]` will do the interpolation for us), and thus potentially have to carry around only, say, seven as opposed to sixty-four colors.

From reading the code given above, you'll note that I already found those transition points for you (hint: check the setting for `GridLines`). Further hints on what those colors might be are furnished by the [documentation for `colormap()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html):

> `jet` ranges from blue to red, and passes through the colors cyan, yellow, and orange.

Could it be? Let's check:

```
cols = RGBColor @@@ Rationalize[cMap];
Position[cols, #][[1, 1]] & /@ {Blue, Cyan, Yellow, 
  Orange // Rationalize, Red}
{8, 24, 40, 48, 56}
```

This just gives the positions of the colors within the array `cols`, but we can rescale things to correspond to the argument range expected of a colormap:

```
(# - 1)/(Length[cols] - 1) & /@ %
{1/9, 23/63, 13/21, 47/63, 55/63}
```

and those are precisely where the breakpoints of the piecewise linear functions corresponding to RGB components of the colormap are. That is five colors; to ensure a smooth interpolation, we add the first and last colors as well to this list,

```
cols[[{1, Length[cols]}]]
{RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16], RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}
```

paring the original `cols` list to a total of seven. Since 7/64 is approximately 11%, this is a pretty big savings.

Thus the color function we seek is

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[
        {{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
         {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, 
                          u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

We make two comparisons to verify `jet[]`. Here's a gradient plot comparing the `ColorFunction`s `jet` and `Blend[cols, #]&`:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{
   Graphics[Raster[{Range[100]/100}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[cols, #] &)], 
    AspectRatio -> .2, ImagePadding -> None, PlotLabel -> "Full", 
    PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   Graphics[Raster[{Range[100]/100}, ColorFunction -> jet], 
    AspectRatio -> .2, ImagePadding -> None, 
    PlotLabel -> "Compressed", PlotRangePadding -> None]}}]
```

[image: color gradient comparison of jet and explicit 64-color Blend]

and here's a mechanical verification that the 64 colors in `cols` are nicely reproduced:

```
Rationalize[Table[jet[k/63], {k, 0, 63}]] === cols
True
```

You can now use `jet[]` as a `ColorFunction` for any plotting function that supports it. Enjoy!