# Dynamic (or forced) scaling of ColorFunction

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753508/custom-colorfunction-colordata-in-arrayplot-and-similar-functions) on importing ColorData from matlab, I was wondering if there is a way to change the range of values over which the ColorFunction is scaled. That was probably not entirely clear, so let me show with a figure from matlab (the same example as in the previous question is used)

[image]

The plot on the left is the original, with the `ColorData` mapped to the data values between `-1` and `1`. Now, I can easily set it to be mapped to the data values between `0` and `1`, the result being that all values less than `0` are assigned blue color (lowest in the colormap). `PlotRange` is the closest function, and using `ClippingStyle` in addition to that produces a similar figure. However, it doesn't re-scale the ColorData to map to the plot range.

How can I do this in Mathematica?

BTW, to insert colorbars using Mathematica, you can look at this [function](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=24)

Comment: Is `ColorFunctionScaling` option useful ?

Comment: @Sasha: I forgot to mention that in my post... I tried using it, but I can only set it to either `True` or `False`. I'm looking for some more flexibility in how I scale it. For e.g., if I'm only interested in the changes in a small region, I can utilize the entire range of the color values for that region.

Comment: @d'o-o'b Why not using RegionFunction[ ]?

Comment: As Brett points out, you use `ColorFunctionScaling` alongside `ColorFunction`. The idea is that setting scaling to false implies that you do the scaling yourself.

Comment: @belisarius please post an example that applies illustrated plot.

Comment: I think you probably can be also interested in [Mathematica `ColorbarPlot` package](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=24) by Will Robertson and Mike Croucher .

Comment: Can also obtain the package (and view its development) from Will's github account: http://github.com/wspr/ColorbarPlot

Comment: @Alexy: Thanks, I already posted that link in my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a function applied to a surface:

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", #3] &), Mesh -> {{1}, {1}}]
```

To look at the top-right corner, with the same color function and scaling, I set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, and manually scale the color function to map the (global) minimum to zero and the maximum to one using `Rescale`:

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", Rescale[#3, {-4, 4}, {0, 1}]] &)]
```

[image: screenshot of the two plots]

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I wanted. Can this also be extended to custom ColorFunctions?

Comment: @d'o-o'b Yes, this applies to any color function.  The key parts are setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and then replacing `#3` by `Rescale[...]`.